# Getting a While loop with cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I am currently working on a new project, only I am stuck at the part that i can't find a way to put a list of players with the info I wanna show...

I currently have this:

JSON DATA:

```
participants    
0   
teamId  100
championId  18
summonerName    "BlackedByLucian"
summonerId  23687629
1   {…}
2   {…}
3   {…}
4   {…}
5   {…}
6   {…}
7   {…}
8   {…}
9   {…}
```

PHP

```
//GET CURRENT GAME DATA
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$get_game=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$get_game = json_decode($get_game, true);

//PLAYER DATA
$PlayerName = $get_game['participants'][0]['summonerName'];
$PlayerTeam = $get_game['participants'][0]['teamId'];
$PlayerChampion = $get_game['participants'][0]['championId'];
```

And I want to show it like this:

```
Player1  | 1 | 23

Player2  | 1 | 27

Player3  | 2 | 25

Player4  | 2 | 24

Player5  | 2 | 11

etc.
```

btw. the 0 in `$get_game variable` means the player id of the json.

Comment: You can use `foreach` to loop thru `$get_game['participants']`

Comment: Something like `foreach($get_game['participants'] as $player ) { $PlayerName = $player['summonerName']; }` see http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Your curl is missing the url. Do you have an example of the json response?

Comment: @Eddie Tried that, didn't work for some reason(Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach())

Comment: What are you getting when you do `print_r($get_game)`? And also post your `foreach` attempt

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of this, utilising a `for` loop. You could also use a `foreach` loop, but I'm old school hehe.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($get_game["participants"]); $i++)
    echo $get_game["participants"][$i]["summonerName"] . " | " . $get_game["participants"][$i]["teamId"] . " | " . $get_game["participants"][$i]["championId"];
```

Comment: This is what happens when I try to answer on my phone  @Phil

Comment: Also, this is no different to `foreach` which OP says they've tried but doesn't work. I'm not saying this is wrong and I'm certainly not assuming OP actually used `foreach` correctly but it's just something to keep in mind. +1

Comment: @Phil yeah, seems they had a syntax error. Thought I might throw my answer out there, just in case it might help him :)